# Multiple planned comparisons of frequencies (based on a binary DV and multiple IV's)

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, z-test, planned-comparisons-test

I'm looking for the most appropriate way to to conduct multiple planned comparisons of frequencies.

I conducted an experiment in which participants could come from one of two groups, 'Group A' and 'Group B'. I can further divide participants in each group by Sex (Male,Female) and one of three age groups (18 to 34, 34 to 54, 55 and over).

I randomly assign participants so that they receive one of four possible questions. Each question consists of a binary result, correct or incorrect.

So I have:

- DV = test result = Binary
- IV = test question = Categorical
- IV = Group (A or B) = Categorical
- IV = Sex (Male or Female) = Categorical
- IV = Age Group (<=18, 19 to 54, =>54) = Ordinal, coded as 1,2,3

There is variance between the cells, but N's are > 50 in all cells.

I want to conduct multiple planned comparisons. E.g. Compare the mean correct answers in test A versus test B for 18 to 34yo Males in Group A. i.e. Did they do significantly better/worse between the tests?

What is the best approach to tackling this?  Could I simply conduct multiple Z-tests with a Bonferroni correction?

Many thanks,
Suggy

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a typical case of [log linear analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-linear_analysis). Think of this like a ANOVA for categorical variables. The Wikipedia page contains several references that will get you started. If you are using Stata you could look [here](http://maartenbuis.nl/presentations/london15b.pdf).

---

Economists tend to use the term log linear analysis for linear regression where the dependent variable is log transformed. This is not how it is used in my field.

Comment: Thank you. I'm digging through the resources on this.

 I'm curious, in this case, as my DV is 0 (incorrect) or 1 (correct) could I use Mann-Whitney U to compare categories?

I've also looked at Logistic Regression and Analysis of Means.  All tests tell me broadly the same thing, but I'm looking for the simplest (appropriate) test.  Many thanks,